# ファイル名が連番になっているか、抜けがないかの確認をする方法

Tags: shellscript

一般的で曖昧な質問なのですが、ターミナル上の操作で大量のファイル、例えば1000個、10000個といったファイルをダウンロード、もしくは生成した時に、

- ファイルがきちんと連番になっているか（途中で変な名前になっているファイルがないか）
- すべての番号のファイルが存在しているか？

といったことをチェックする際に、みなさんはどういう手段を使っていますか？（ダウンロードや生成時のエラーで、ごく少数の不具合が発生するものとします）

もちろんPython等で簡単なスクリプト等を書けばそういうことはできるとは思うのですが、実際にはいくつかのコマンドを利用してシェルの中で作業を終わらせるべきなのかなと思います。
完璧な方法はないかも知れませんが、オススメの方法、実際の業務上の知見などありましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: うーむ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236164/how-to-find-missing-files-with-sequential-names

Comment: ちょっと回答としては広い印象があります。もう少し目的や課題を絞ったほうがいいかもしれないです。スタックオーバーフローではアンケートや市場調査目的だとちょっとオフトピック気味な印象があります

Comment: ファイル数の多さはあまり重要じゃなくて、ファイル名のパターンや総ファイル数があらかじめ分かっているか辺りの方が肝になりませんか？

Comment: そうですね。ファイル名のパターンや、総ファイル数の把握みたいな方が大事ですね。

Comment: 例えば `hoge0001` から `hoge1000` までのファイルがあるとした場合、｢抜けている」ファイルを見つけるのに `seq -f 'hoge%04g' 1000 | grep -v -x -f <(ls -1 hoge????)` とする方法があります。

Comment: `seq -f 'hoge%04g' 1000` いいっすね!

 `diff <(seq -f 'hoge%04g' 1000) <(ls -1 hoge????)` を思いつきました

Answer (score 1):

生成する際はプログラムが生成するはずなので抜けはないはず。
ダウンロードの際には `tar` や `zip` でまとめて一括ダウンロードすれば抜けはないはず。

ってことで「ダウンロードの際」にはチェックしないです。
ダウンロード後の分析の際にはアーカイブ中のファイル数を数えるだけですね。目視で数える必要もなし `wc` なり `dired` の行数なりで判断すれば問題ないはず。

Comment: そうですね。ファイル数を `wc` でチェックするのは手間もかかりませんし、一つの重要なアイディアですね。（ただし、この質問は抜けは発生する防げないという前提でしています…

Comment: 抜けが発生しているかどうか知りたいだけならファイル数（＝ファイルを列挙したテキストの行数）が不一致であるかどうかだけで十分です。オイラの回答はここまでを想定。具体的にどのファイルが抜けているかを知る必要があるんスか？